# Laravel 4.2 Vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am working in laravel 4.2 and I want to implement Vue.js into my application. When I put some testing code in my blade it only shows error that "Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message'"I know that laravel read {{message}} like php code but do you know any solution how to add vue.js to my blade? Thanks for help.
Here is code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'hello from Vue.js 2.0'
    }
})
</script>
<div id="app">
<p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you using laravel 4.2?

Comment: Company that I am working in using laravel 4.2

Comment: So no one doesn't know how to upgrade? Sorry for being so rude...But you will need to upgrade at some point. It is only a matter of time when will someone find a security flaw or some exploit. Don't use old software!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `@` before print message veriable

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    message: 'hello from Vue.js 2.0'
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
    <div id="app">
        <p>@{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: when I add @ it load my page without laravel errors but only show {{message}} not actually my message data.

Comment: You need to add jquery library and and vuejs code in document ready portion

Comment: Ok I find solution. I put script tag on down on my page not on a top.

Answer (score 1):

escape the code using @

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'hello from Vue.js 2.0'
    }
})
</script>
<div id="app">
<p>@{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

See **Displaying Raw Text With Curly Braces** section [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates)